# Are there any major differences when programming of the Pi and for normal Linux

Tags: python

As the title says, are there any major differences in programming with Python on the RPi and a normal PC with linux?

And if there are (excluding the GPIO and other platform specific stuff) could you list(or at least provide a basic list with the differences)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not much difference since RaspberryPi is quite normal Linux system. The only difference is that it uses ARM architecture instead of x86 and compared to the recent computers it's slower, has less RAM and has some other peripherals (like GPIO and lack of HDD).

When programming in high level languages like Python, you wont see any difference between different CPU architectures. So the only difference is amount of resources - programming on typical desktop computer you usually don't have to worry about speed and memory footprint as much as on RaspberryPi.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought from reading, but I wanted to make sure as I haven't got my Pi yet (sad_face)

As additional info, just to confirm, frameworks like: Twisted, Django and etc. are fully working on the Pi

Comment: Yes, they should work exactly as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Raspbian and the other general purpose pi distros are the same as their "normal" (x86 et. al.) counter-parts; they only differ in so far as the binaries are compiled for the pi.  The reason this is necessary is that while Debian, Fedora, etc. do release official versions for various architectures including some ARM, the particular processor on the pi is too obscure, so people have had to fork off their own distributions.  You won't quite have the same size repos to draw upon, but what is there is the same.  WRT python, this means that whatever depends upon a native library that hasn't been ported won't work, but I would guess 95%+ of modules usually available in distro packages are there.

Comment: The processor is not obscure and official Debian for `armel` will work out of the box. Problem is, it won't make use of hardware floating point unit, however. Official `armhf` (which should use hardware floating point) on the other hand wont work, as it is designed to work only on newer ARM processors.